# Udev rule to adjust mouse speed not working (but executing)

Tags: usb, udev, mouse

## Summary

I want to use a `udev` rule to adjust the speed of a certain mouse when I attach it.
I can get the `udev` rule to fire, but it does not successfully adjust the mouse speed. However, when I manually execute the command, it does work.
What am I doing wrong?

### `99-mouse-connect.rules` file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/`

```bash
ACTION=="add", \
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTRS{idVendor}=="062a", \
ATTRS{idProduct}=="5918", \
ENV{DISPLAY}=":0", \
ENV{XAUTHORITY}="/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/notify-send 'Adjusting MOSART mouse speed...'", \
RUN+="/usr/bin/xinput --list | /usr/bin/sed -n -E '/MOSART Semi\. 2\.4G Keyboard Mouse\s*id=.*pointer/s/.*=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | /usr/bin/xargs -I {} /usr/bin/xinput set-prop {} 'libinput Accel Speed' -1"
```

It even shows the system notification.
Again, the last command works when I execute it manually. Why does it not work in a udev rule?

## What I tried

- I tried to put the command(s) into a separate script and replace
  the last four lines in the udev rule with

  ```bash
  RUN+="path/to/script.sh"
  ```

  where

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  export DISPLAY=:0
  export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority

  /usr/bin/notify-send 'Adjusting MOSART mouse speed...'
  /usr/bin/xinput --list | /usr/bin/sed -n -E '/MOSART Semi\. 2\.4G 
  Keyboard Mouse\s*id=.*pointer/s/.*=([0-9]+).*/\1/p' | 
  /usr/bin/xargs -I {} /usr/bin/xinput set-prop {} 'libinput Accel Speed' -1
  ```

  is the content of that file. But this also did not work.
- I also tried `ACTION=="bind"` as [suggested here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=274909#:%7E:text=I%20had%20the%20same%20problem.%20My%20solution%20was%20to%20trigger%20the%20udev%20rule%20with%20ACTION%3D%3D%22bind%22%20instead%20of%20ACTION%3D%3D%22add%22%20(Because%20I%20saw%20with%20udevadm%20monitor%20that%20it%20was%20last%20action%20when%20I%20connected%20a%20mouse))